# Explanation of a 45-degree 2D rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am trying to understand how 2D matrix transformation works. Let's say I have a point `(1, 1)`. The angle it makes with X axis is $\theta = 45°$ and I want to rotate the point (around origin) by additional 45 degrees, placing it at `(0, √2)`.

[image: Example]

I know that 2D rotation matrix is provided by:

$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta\\\sin \theta & \cos \theta\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\cos 45 & -\sin 45\\\sin 45 & \cos 45\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5253 & -0.8509\\0.8509 & 0.5253\end{bmatrix}$

So now all I have to do to get `(0, √2)` is multiply the two out:

$\begin{bmatrix}0.5253 & -0.8509\\0.8509 & 0.5253\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0.5253 - 0.8509\\0.8509 + 0.5253\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-0.3256\\1.3762\end{bmatrix} \neq \begin{bmatrix}0\\1.4142\end{bmatrix}$

What went wrong here?

Comment: I don't know how you got your numbers, but $\cos(45°) = \sin(45°) = \cos(\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4) = \frac 1{\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: It's your calculator. When you are calculating with degrees, make sure you have put on DEG and not RAD.

Comment: I was using MATLAB and it turns out $cos(\theta) \neq cosd(\theta)$

Comment: MATLAB uses RAD by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were using radians.  45 radians = 8100/pi degrees; 45 degrees = pi/4 radians.  Use cos(pi/4) and sin(pi/4), or else change your calculator to degree mode.

Comment: Rookie mistake. We've all been there.. right? Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely.  Happy to collect the points.

Comment: For something that was already in the comments when you wrote the answer...

Comment: @amsmath my answer was 28 minutes ago, your comment was 25 minutes ago

Comment: @Empy2 I am super sorry. Appearently I cannot subtract... I apologize.